# Google Chrome Full Black Screen

Tags: google-chrome

I'm facing a weird problem.

If a webpage includes jquery graphs or libraries the page loads with a full black screen. I can see the source code and the mouse pointer finds the buttons or links. I uninstalled and reinstall chrome with the latest version but still no chance.

Comment: Not sure whether this is really on-topic... Anyways, where do you see the source code? On the screenshot there's only black

Comment: The classic way, right click, show source.

Comment: Do you have any source code you could post? pastebin.com?

Comment: It's happening on wordpress "site stats" graphs. It's really weird cuz when I minimize the "site stats" bar on my wordpress panel the black screen gone, when I open the panel the black screen comes back. And I tried with other computers, the problem doesn't exists.. I've start using Firefox again :(

Comment: Make sure you report a bug with Chrome: http://new.crbug.com. Include a minimal HTML page that will reproduce it.

Comment: Experiencing the same black screen, but it appears temperamental. It will work 6 times in a row on the same page, then black for 2-3 times, then back to working.

Comment: This also occurs with Photoshop and other graphically intense applications sometimes. Hopefully the second solution on here will fix it, as I do indeed have an AMD card.

Comment: I've noticed this is happening in Google search when typing terms like "weather <zipcode>" or "<band> discography" - so I think it's something related to rendering those widgets.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Same thing just happened to me on Google Chrome v22.0.1221.1 (Nvidia GPU).
The workaround was to disable *GPU compositing on all pages* (setting available on `chrome://flags/`)

If it happens in Chrome version > 45.x, See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32955808/293023 by @detale.

Use `google-chrome -disable-gpu` from the command line to temporary disable gpu.

Comment: yes this solves the problem but it looks like that with such configuration Chrome uses much more cpu. I noticed this because after the forced reload my UPS started beeping for overload (never happened before!)

Comment: btw this is the current thread on the Chrome forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/NAaYwqE73OU/Biwd59pHpHEJ

Comment: this for linux users
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/linux/tXl_eSgGpcM

Comment: still a problem with nvidia GPUs, in version Version 27.0.1453.116, fix still works

Comment: Happening for me in VirtualBox, the fix in this answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: Always got a black screen, also when opening chrome://flags/ so can't change anything

Comment: I disabled it changing Chrome config file: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State. Add the section:
"hardware_acceleration_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },

Comment: If you have a built-in Intel graphics card, but are using a faster card (e.g. NVIDIA) and you don't want to disable hardware acceleration in Chrome, you can also try to disable the Intel card in the Device Manager.(Win+Pause -> Device Manager -> Look for "Display adapters" -> Right-click "Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics ..." -> Disable)

Comment: The setting is no longer in chrome://flags. See answer below by @detale

Comment: It appears that if your GPU changed (including if you switched between Optimus and non-Optimus configuration on notebooks with switchable graphics), the GPU cache data can cause problems.  https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/ctn3pb/black_chrome_window_after_gpu_swap/exmjcsq solved the issue for me.

Comment: As a footnote for reference, if turning off the hardware acceleration, using online tools such as figma will become very slow. When you notice it, you will probably forget that it is related to hardware acceleration settings. That's happened to me after a few months of turning it off then using the figma for some reason.

Answer (score 17):

If it happens in Chrome version > 45.x,

(1) try: System | Settings | Advanced settings

     uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available", restart chrome.

(2) If (1) doesn't help, **restart your computer**

(3) If the black screen still occurs, try Chrome Cleanup Tool to reset your chrome.
     https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/

Comment: Why does this occur btw?

Comment: @Pacerier It is browser rendering issue, very likely a bug in Chrome itself.

Comment: Here is a quick completely restartless solution for occasional back windows that doesn't require disabling GPU acceleration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346056/603516

Answer (score 11):

You can turn off GPU usage by Chrome without Windows restart in safe mode. Options:

1) by inserting section in Chrome config file "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State":

```
"hardware_acceleration_mode": { "enabled": false },
```

2) chrome.exe --disable-gpu

Answer (score 9):

if you can't see the `chrome://flags` because everything is black, and you don't want to revert your graphic driver as @wilfo did, then you can run `google-chrome --disable-gpu` from the console.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/chromium-doesn%27t-work-after-update-4175522748/

Comment: Thanks. I was having problems with this when setting up a vagrant development box. If you want to make sure the flag is always set, run `sudo sed -i 's/google\-chrome\-stable/google\-chrome\-stable \-\-disable-gpu/g' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`, exchanging the path to whereever  your launcher config is (this is for ubuntu).

Answer (score 4):

i have resolved this by following steps.

1) Go to customise icon in the top right corner chrome.
2) click on
       more tools option.
3) Click task manager.
4) Kill/end process GPU process

**This has resolved my issue of black screen in chrome.**

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Adblock extension, make sure you add the domain into the exception list. I had that problem with Google Analytics

Comment: I do have the Adblock extension. But what domain?

Answer (score 1):

**Disable** Nvidia's **nView Desktop Manager** and the problem should resolve.

Comment: this did it for me, while disabling gpu support did not

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:
(I got this answer from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/MJjuK65Exkg)

1. Unpin Chrome icon from task bar so it is on the desktop.
2. Right mouse click on said icon and left click on Properties.
3. Click on Shortcuts tab
   4A. In Target window, add this exact text: [space]--disable-gpu"
   4B. The end of the text string in the Target window should now read: ...chrome.exe" --disable-gpu"
4. Double click on the desktop icon and Chrome should open correctly. If you want, you may pin this icon to the taskbar.
5. Left single click on the "Customize" icon in the top right, which is the 3 horizontal lines icon. Select "Settings" from the list.
6. Select "Show advanced settings..." at the bottom.
7. Deselect "Use hardware acceleration when available."

Comment: I have found opening a new window can fix the other windows sometimes. (Ctrl + N)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an AMD/ATI graphics card. If so go to Catalyst Control Centre and switch Chrome to use only the Intel HD graphics (power saving).
It is a problem with Chrome 18 and it is being fixed shortly (as advised by google six hours before this post)

It fixed after switched the graphics card in Catalyst, then restarted the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, on Ubuntu though, started just over a month ago.
What did it for me was to revert my Nvidia driver back to its stable version (I've been using the alleged unstable version for a couple of months now).

Anyway, it's worth a shot:
Open "System Settings" and under the "Hardware Tab" go to "Additional Drivers".
You should see on the list a driver called: "Nvidia Binary Xorg Driver..." - activate it.

Hope this helps to Ubuntu users out there..

Answer (score 0):

All google chrome extensios crashed and then black screen on the window for my case.. tried uninstall and installed.. but no use..
Finally I restarted the computer.. It worked for me.. And i disabled adblock on google homepage. works pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users - Instead of changing the settings within the Chrome browser, which risks propagating them to other machines that do not have that issue, it is best to just edit the .desktop launcher:

Open the appropriate file for your situation.

```
/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
```

Just append the flag (-disable-gpu) to the end of the three Exec= lines in your file.

```
...
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U -disable-gpu
...
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable -disable-gpu
...
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito -disable-gpu
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about the environment you're running. This problem occurs on VirtualBox when running on Windows 10. One thing you can try is disabling 3D Acceleration on your VM, this is a known issue.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14985

Answer (score 0):

I still experience occasional black screens with latest Chrome 60 with GPU acceleration enabled by default (probably caused by lack of free memory for numerous tabs).

Sometimes it helps to kill GPU process in builtin Task manager (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) as @amit suggests. But sometimes this forces more Chrome windows to become black while some others may remain normal.

I've noticed that tabs headers and address bar of black windows remain funtional and tabs can be fully repaired just by dragging them out of black windows. But it's too tedious to do this one by one when their number is huge.

So here is quick completely restartless solution inspired by [Merging windows of Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/161893/merging-windows-of-google-chrome/776919#776919):

- Add a new empty tab to black window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- Left-click the first tab in the window
- Then hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and left-click the right most tab just before the empty one
- Drag all the selected tabs at once out of the black window
- Close the black window with remaining single empty tab